# Storing different-sized objects in dynamic char array (alignment?)

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, char

I am making a memory pool implementation which can store objects of derived types of some template type `T`. The current implementation is here (The interesting class is at the bottom, `BaseMemoryPool`): http://pastebin.com/exgkzSyT

I didn't post the code here as it's longer than necessary for me to ask my main point; how can I safely (with regards to alignment, block alignment, and so on) and with no performance penalty cast some portion of a dynamically allocated `char` array to some templated type `U`?

A sketch of what I'm trying to do:

```
template <typename U>
U *setAndReturnPointer(U &&object, char *storage, size_t storageLength, size_t byteOffset) {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, typename std::decay<U>::type>::value, "item must be of or derived of type Base");
    assert(byteOffset + sizeof(U) <= storageLength);

    U *ptr = reinterpret_cast<U*>(&storage[byteOffset]);
    *ptr = std::forward<U>(item);
    return ptr;
}
```

I have a feeling I'm getting into a whole swamp of alignment and memory errors here and so on. I'd greatly appreciate some guidance and learning how this can be done, or if it can't be done, what alternatives there are. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: It also looks like you're going to get kicked by not calling constructors..

Comment: Isn't the area in memory I want initialized with the item `item`? Or do you mean another constructor?

Comment: No, `*ptr = std::forward<U>(item);` assumes an object already exists at `*ptr` and calls its assignment operator, not a constructor.

Comment: Bombax, this is risky business. For example, consider a `U` that contains a string member `str`. `str` = `source.str` is doomed because `str` was never properly initialized. Crom knows where `source.str` is going to be copied to.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, both of you. I have read about "placement new" now and it seems this is really quite complicated as I have to call the destructor manually. Perhaps it is best to search for existing implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example given for `std::align` answered my question perfectly and taught me more about how alignment works.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align